# MATLAB's audioread for MP3 files on Linux

Tags: matlab, gstreamer

I fail to read MP3 files with MATLAB's [audioread](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html):

```
>> audioread('file.mp3')
Error using audioread (line 88)
The file type is not supported
```

I am on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) and have MATLAB R2016a installed. I already have done the workaround for [this bug](https://de.mathworks.com/login?uri=/support/bugreports/1246784). (Link against my system's more recent libstdc++.)

As far as I understand, MATLAB uses gstreamer 0.1 and I suppose to have `gstreamer0.1-fluendo-mp3` installed. However, this doesn't exist in the packages, only gstreamer 1.0 is available:

```
$ apt-cache search gstreamer fluendo-mp3 
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 - Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 1.0 plugin
```

If I am on the right track with the gstreamer issue: Can I tell MATLAB to use gstreamer 1.0 instead of 0.1? Or is there any PPA for `gstreamer0.1-fluendo-mp3`?

Comment: I think it is `libstdc++` that is causing the problem (but I am not sure). check out this to see if it helps http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94531-why-do-i-receive-an-error-when-creating-a-videoreader-object-on-linux-in-matlab-r2010b-7-11 - otherwise contact Matlab support for instructions. Really hard to investigate without recreating the problem..

Comment: I have already done this workaround. `readlink -f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` returns `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21`.

Comment: do you want to try installing the following packages? `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev`
 `sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` I suggest you look at what they are before you install. Similar issue reported here https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/250220-matlab-cannot-find-codecs-on-linux - as you said, it is a version issue.

Comment: I could install the packages of the first command, but they did not solved the problem. I could not install the packages of the second command. `E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' has no installation candidate` `E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Mathworks support. This functionality is currently not available under Ubuntu 16.04 and there is no workaround. It is intended to be fixed in a future MATLAB release.